# JQuery - show/hide rows and manipulate css

Tags: jquery, html, css

while searching for a solution for my problem I came across this thread:
Show/Hide Table Rows using javascript classes
[Show/Hide Table Rows using javascript classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797064/show-hide-table-rows-using-javascript-classes)

I went for Vape's solution (No. 4) and it worked perfectly well.
But there was some more stuff to do:
I'm using a css background image (a simple circle with a 'plus-sign' in it for the
rows that hold the click event).
Clicking on the plus-sign opens the underlying rows. So far so good.
After expanding the rows I need to change the plus-sign to a minus-sign, signalling this way that the rows can be hidden again.
After some fiddling about (I'm pretty useless in JQuery/Javascript - yet! I've only just started...),  I managed to toggle the css classes cat-plus and cat-minus.
The problem is that there are more rows than one that can be expanded.
But each time an expandable row is clicked, the plus-sign changes to a minus-sign on ALL of the other expandable rows, although of course they remain collapsed, because they haven't been clicked.

I know I will have to take into account the data-prod-cat of the row that is clicked, but I can't figure out how to do that.

The example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/8gbLagjz/

**Here's the HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Destination</td>
    <td>Updated on</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1"><span class="cat-plus">+ On Store</span></a></td>
    <td>22/10</td>
</tr>
<tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>City 1</td>
    <td>22/10</td>
</tr>
<tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
    <td></td>
    <td>140</td>
    <td>City 2</td>
    <td>22/10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat="2"><span class="cat-plus">+ On Store</span></a></td>
    <td>22/10</td>
</tr>
<tr class="cat2" style="display:none">
    <td></td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>City 1</td>
    <td>22/10</td>
</tr>
<tr class="cat2" style="display:none">
    <td></td>
    <td>140</td>
    <td>City 2</td>
    <td>22/10</td>
</tr>
```

**The Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggler").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.cat'+$(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
    $(".cat-plus").toggleClass("cat-minus");
});
```

});

**The CSS**

```
.cat-plus {background-image:url("../images/plus.png"); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:-15px center; border-left: 20px solid green;}
.cat-minus {background-image:url("../images/minus.png"); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:-15px center; border-left: 20px solid red;}
```

I've swapped the images with a green (for +) and red (for -) background, since I've seen
no way to integrate images here. But you'll see what I'm after anyway.
In this example I don't want the second row to turn red when the first row is being clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to your problem:

link to jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/8gbLagjz/5/

The main issue your were having was selecting the span class that contained your 
cat-plus class.  Since it is a child of your anchor tag you have to go up a level using
the Jquery parent() function and then find the span that contains your .cat-plus class
using the find() function. After finding the span you can then use toggleClass() to toggle 
the .cat-plus class.

I only had to make changes to your JavaScript, below is the changes I made:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){


        $(".toggler").click(function(e){

          e.preventDefault();

            //the data stored in the data-prod-cat
            var prodCat = ($(this).attr("data-prod-cat"));

           //toggle the link clicked on
           $(".cat" + prodCat).toggle();


           //select the parent and find the span so you can
          //toggle the "cat-plus" class
          $(this).parent().find("span").toggleClass("cat-plus");

         //toggle the cat-minus class
         $(this).toggleClass("cat-minus");        

        });
      });
```

Comment: thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Still a long way to go for me - as I mentioned I have only just begun to learn JS/JQuery - but your code is perfectly readable to me, so this is another step in getting the hang with this stuff. Cheers

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help

Comment: If you want you can click on the check mark next to the answer to accept it as the answer to your question.

Comment: no problem, I hope your Jquery/Javascript learning goes well. It looks like your are beginning to get the basic idea behind it pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this line isn't doing what you want:

```
$(".cat-plus").toggleClass("cat-minus");
```

Instead you probably want:

```
$(".cat-plus").addClass("cat-minus").removeClass(".cat-plus");
```

Comment: Thanks Gavin, this looks logical to me, but the toggling of the cat-plus/cat-minus thingy actually worked. It was just that ALL expandable rows were affected, which was not intended. I'll certainly play around with your code anyway, so it's very appreciated. Cheers